# Is it bad practice to populate this array using a for loop?

Tags: iphone, swift

Please forgive me for asking what is probably a real beginners question. My search on google and stackoverflow didn't produce anything conclusive.

My array needs to contain the numbers 0 through 59. Here is a simple for loop to populate the array:

```
var timeArray = [0]
count = 1

while count < 60 {
    timeArray.append(count)
    count++
}
```

On the other hand, I could do this:

```
var timeArray = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59]
```

The second I guess is faster and maybe more readable. The first is maybe more concise.

What is general best practice in this case? Is there another, beter alternative?

Thanks.

Comment: I dont see any reason why a loop should be considered "bad practice" if it is doing exactly what you want. "bad practice" usually is also a very unscientific pseudoscientific argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are right the for loop will be slower that the second one.
I would use the second option but with slightly different syntax, just to save typings:

```
var timeArray = Array(0..<60)
```

Comment: `[0..<59]` does *not* give the same result. What you probably meant is `Array(0 ... 59)` :)